# x.commerece the requested page cannot be found

Tags: android, paypal

I am trying to download this package to see how to integrate paypal with my app
however, every time i click it, it says the requested site cannot be found, even though i was once able to download this package, but unfortunately deleted it

https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/PayPal_MECL_1.0_Android-Developer-Package_0.zip

how to fix this? i'd like to download this package

Answer (score 0):

I just clicked the link you provided and the PayPal MECL for the Android was downloaded. Are you still having issues with it?

Code samples from X.com are going to all be deleted soon. They're moving to Developer.PayPal.com and github - http://paypal.github.io/

I don't believe the MECL stuff is going to be added - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Lena, this FAQ may be helpful to you:

> Where is the Mobile Express Checkout Library (MECL)?
>
> The Mobile Express Checkout Library for iOS and Android have been
>   discontinued. We recommend using the new PayPal iOS SDK and Paypal
>   Android SDK instead. For developers with existing Express Checkout
>   integrations or who want additional features such as authorization and
>   capture, we recommend Mobile Express Checkout.

Source:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/faq/#mobile-sdk-questions

Comment: will it work for israeli credit cards ? i am in israel and most if not all of my clients are in israel

Comment: @LenaBru

Mobile Express Checkout is available almost everywhere PayPal is accepted, with certain exceptions due to legal constraints.

See here under "International availability and fees" for more info:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-express-checkout/